# 'Word cannot do this because a dialog box is open' error in using Interop.Word

Tags: c#, printing, office-interop

I have a function that creates word documents using a template. After creating, it sends all created documents to printer. If there is no another open word document, it prints  them correctly. But if there is an another open word document, i see a warning box that says '***Word can not do this because a dialog box is open***'. After closing that box, when i check print queue, i see that the list is incomplete. Some of documents are missing. 
Is there a way to send multiple word documents to print queue without closing other open word documents?

My code below:

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();
Word.Document aDoc = null;
//...
aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open();
aDoc.Activate();
aDoc.SaveAs(ref fileName, ref missing,..)
aDoc.Close();
paths.Add(fileName);
object saveChanges=false;
object obj = Missing.Value;
wordApp.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref obj, ref obj);

foreach(string var in paths)
{
   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(var);
   info.Verb = "Print";
   info.RedirectStandardError = false;
   info.Arguments = printername;
   info.CreateNoWindow = true;
   info.ErrorDialog = false;
   info.UseShellExecute = true;
   info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   Process.Start(info);
}
```

Comment: Is your Word Interop document visible? (default is visible, far as i remember). If so, try changing to visible = false and see what the outcome is.

Comment: Try setting it to true then, and see if you get any dialogues that you fail to answer since it's hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advices. I solved my problem.

I realized that, during sending to printer, the processes are interfering each other. The new process is starting before the previous one ends. So i needed to wait for previous process ends. **WaitForExit**() provided that. And i changed my code in this way:

```
foreach(string var in paths)
{
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(var);
info.Verb = "Print";
info.RedirectStandardError = false;
info.Arguments = printername;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.ErrorDialog = false;
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process cmd = Process.Start(info);
cmd.WaitForExit();
}
```

And it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it sounds more like a Word configuration problem than coding problem.

Anyway, I digged a little bit and found this configuration:

In your Microsoft Word > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View > uncheck all

Give it a try, and post results please.

This recommendation is an answer for [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5abc6887-1c0c-451e-a9ed-95b6b56af674/opening-a-word-2013-doc-from-outlook-2007-word-cannot-open-because-a-dialog-box-is-open-please?forum=word) question, at technet.microsoft forum.